# wpf bind a controlitem to collection

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, binding

hey there 
i am having problem i have

```
   List<List<memoryCard>>
```

that i want to show in my xmal in a button how can I bind my button to the data i want thos is my usercontrol :

<

```
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ButtonControlTemplate1" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Grid>
  <!--i think this is the place where i make mistake :-->
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=CardWasfounded}"/>
            <Rectangle Margin="4,5,8,2" Stroke="Black" RadiusX="45" RadiusY="45" StrokeThickness="3"/>
    </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate_Level2">
        <Button Content="{Binding}" Height="40" Width="50" Margin="4,4,4,4"  Template="{DynamicResource ButtonControlTemplate1}"/>
    </DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate_Level1">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding }" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource DataTemplate_Level2}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
</DataTemplate>
```

I want every button to have binding to this memory card

```
 class memoryCard : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region c'tor
    public memoryCard(Brush _buttonColor)
    {
        buttonColor=_buttonColor;
    }
    #endregion

    #region allReadyFoundedCard

    bool cardWasfounded = false;
        public bool CardWasfounded
        {
            get
            {
                return cardWasfounded;
            }
            set
            {
                if (cardWasfounded != value)
                {
                    cardWasfounded = value;
                    if (PropertyChanged != null)
                    {
                        PropertyChanged(this,
                        new PropertyChangedEventArgs("cardWasfounded"));

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        #endregion 

    #region colorofbutton
        string name = "sdasdas";
        public Brush buttonColor;
        public Brush ButtonColor
        {
            get
            {
                return buttonColor;
            }
            set
            {
                if (buttonColor != value)
                {
                    buttonColor = value;
                    if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this,
                        new PropertyChangedEventArgs("buttonColor"));
                }
            }
        }
        #endregion

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
            }
        }

        #endregion
}
```

whom i want to bind to one of my grids this way :

using this mainwindow class:

```
 public MainWindow()
    {
        List<List<memoryCard>> lsts = new List<List<memoryCard>>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            lsts.Add(new List<memoryCard>());

            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
                lsts[i].Add(new memoryCard(Brushes.Green));
            }
        }

        InitializeComponent();

        lst.ItemsSource = lsts; 
    }
```

Comment: In both your properties, you duplicate the code in NotifyPropertyChanged(string info) in each of the respective setters.

Comment: what is the meaning of that ? isnt this the right way to impment it ?

Comment: The way is correct, its just a duplication of code. instead of checking for whether property changed is null in each setter, you've already set up a method NotifyPropertyChanged to do it for you. So just call the method instead. reduces code duplication and bloat.

Comment: OK so it's not the point I have bigger issues here:)

Comment: Yah, just thought id let you know, meanwhile im working on a solution for you. Except that you mention buttons and there is a button colour property, but nowhere in the listed XAML is there any reference to an actual button. But i think i get what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so from what i've gathered you've got a collection of collections of a custom data type which contains a colour that you'd like to bind to.

So heres a small demo that you should (hopefully) be able to expand.

XAML:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyCollection}" 
              Height="300" Width="600">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Expander Header="Open Me">
                <ItemsControl DataContext="{Binding}" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button DataContext="{Binding}"
                                    Background="{Binding Path=ButtonColor}"
                                    Content="{Binding Path=CardWasFounded}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </Expander>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

And in the code behind:

```
public ObservableCollection<List<memoryCard>> MyCollection {get; set;}

public MainWindow()
{
    DataContext = this;
    MyCollection = new ObservableCollection<List<memoryCard>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        List<memoryCard> list = new List<memoryCard>();

        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            list.Add(new memoryCard(Brushes.Green));
        }
        MyCollection.Add(list);
    }

    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Is this similar to what you're trying to do?

Comment: thank you it seemes like the right path to walk through but it doesnt work for me , can you edit it exactly as it's in your project?

Comment: I've updated an issue in the top collection binding in the XAML. i left in my test collection instead of binding to MyCollection. Try this new solution. if there is still a problem, ill break it down into finer chunks.

Answer (score 0):

When you raise the PropertyChanged event your parameter name (the string you pass in event arguments) must match **exactly** to the property you bind to. This involves case sensitivity.

You do `new PropertyChangedEventArgs("buttonColor")` when the property is actually `ButtonColor`. This will make the WPF binding system ignore the event (since it determines it doesn't have a matching binding so it doesn't have to do anything). You have the same problem with `CardWasFounded`